# Sum values of a Dictionary for specific keys C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, generic-collections

I have a dictionary with two similar keys, one is misspelled so it created another key, that I would like to sum the values of, and delete the key/value pair that is misspelled.

If I have a dictionary of departments, with the department name as the key, and the number of personnel in that department as the value, I would like to sum the values for "Marketing" and "Marketin" and delete the misspelled key/value pair "Marketin".

```
        var departments = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            { "HR", 33 },
            { "Management", 8 },
            { "Marketing", 21 },
            { "Marketin", 4 },
            { "Sales", 44 }
        };
```

I would like the dictionary to look like this:

```
        var departments = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            { "HR", 33 },
            { "Management", 8 },
            { "Marketing", 25 },
            { "Sales", 44 }
        };
```

The dictionary is already created, so I only used an initialization for illustration purposes.

Comment: Where is the typo coming from? Is this data in a database that needs to eventually be written back to it? Is it not sensible to fix the typo at the source?

Comment: It is, I will eventually, this was just to show some data on a dashboard, for now. So, I'll eventually fix it at the source, which is a database.

Comment: Coding Hacks explicitly, to fixes mistakes that were make will just cause a web of band ads, you should fix your data not your code

Comment: @johnny 5 Very true, I'm fixing it right now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
departments["Marketing"] += departments["Marketin"];

departments.Remove("Marketin");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my sketch for more "generic" method:

```
var normalisedDepartments = 
   departments.GroupBy(x => Normalise(x.Key), y => y.Value)
             .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Sum());

    private static string Normalise(string key)
    {
        if (key == "Marketin")
        {
            return "Marketing";
        }
        return key;
    }
```

Then you can tweak Normalise method so that it recognizes other malformed keys, should there be more of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code sample that illustrates the Dictionary capabilities that you can use to do what you want.

As for which combination of these functions that you need to use to accomplish your exact purpose, I'll leave that as an exercise for you.  If you need more help. leave a comment explaining exactly what you don't understand.

```
//how to get a value in your dictionary
string myValue = departments["Marketin"];

//how to update a value in your dictionary
departments["Marketing"] = 5;

//how to remove a value in your dictionary
departments.Remove("Marketin");

//how to iterate over your dictionary
foreach(var department in departments)
{
    //only print the value if it's "Marketin"
    if(department.Key == "Marketin")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(department.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to sum the values for "Marketing" and "Marketin" and delete the misspelled key/value pair "Marketin".

Here is one where the user has identified the problem text and the proper text and then removes the improper(s) and adds (sums) the values to the proper key's value.

```
var departments = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    { "HR", 33 },
    { "Management", 8 },
    { "Marketing", 21 },
    { "Marketin", 4 },
    { "Sales", 44 }
};

var baseText  = "Market";
var validText = "Marketing";

var removal = departments.ToList()
                         .Where(itm => itm.Key.StartsWith(baseText) && 
                                       itm.Key.Equals(validText) == false)
                         .ToList();   

removal.ForEach(itm => departments.Remove(itm.Key));

departments[validText] += removal.Sum(itm => itm.Value);
```

With a final result:

[image]

Comment: This isn't the best Idea what about for other departments with the same prefix like MarketPlace, we don't have all the data here it is better to be explicit

Comment: @johnny5 This code can be generi-cised into a method for use on other department keys. I am only coding to the current spec.

Comment: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @johnny5 The ends justifies the means.

Comment: Not in this case, Creating a more versatile hack to solve issues in the data will only promote not fixing the true root of the cause which is bad data.

Comment: Also. A prefix can cause more bugs than before,  What happens if the first letter of the department was a type, are you then going to create a post fix parameter?  Why stop there then why not allow the user to input their own regex of how to describe the typo?  Do you see how this can lead down the wrong path really easily, if you going to make a hack for this it should be explicit.